# sql - values after the 1st and 2nd space

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

I'd like to break down a field into 3 parts, using the spaces `' '`

**Example**

```
select name from nametable;
```

All the information is in the same field. eg `'dr john smith'`, `'mrs jane smith'`.

I'd like the results to be broken up into 3 columns:

```
select title, firstname, lastname from nametable
```

eg:

> 'dr' as title, 'john' as firstname, 'smith' as lastname
>
> 'mrs' as title, 'jane' as firstname, 'smith' as lastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parsename()` function, like this:

```
declare @name varchar(100) = 'Mr John Nash'

select  parsename(Replace(@name , ' ', '.'), 3) as title,
        parsename(Replace(@name, ' ', '.'), 2) as firstName,
        parsename(Replace(@name, ' ', '.'), 1) as lastName;
```

In case you have periods in your `@name`, you can use this:

```
declare @name varchar(100) = 'Mr. John Nash'


select  Replace(parsename(Replace(Replace(@name, '.', '*') , ' ', '.'), 3), '*', '.') as title,
        Replace(parsename(Replace(Replace(@name, '.', '*'), ' ', '.'), 2), '*', '.') as firstName,
        Replace(parsename(Replace(Replace(@name, '.', '*'), ' ', '.'), 1), '*', '.') as lastName;
```

Here you first replace the `.` with a symbol that you never see, for example a `*`. and at the end you replace that `*` with a `.` again.

Comment: This does have a flaw, it will not find anything if the name contains more than 3 spaces or contains period + 3 spaces. 'Mr. John Nash'. If it contains period it will return wrong result

Comment: I guess you mean 2 spaces. The question says it has only 3 columns: title, firstname, lastname. For the period there is a simple solution that I'll add. @t-clausen.dk

Comment: no, I mean 3 spaces. And the simple solution is replacing the period with a different value and replacing it back after the parsename

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I don't get it, can you please give an example. If you mean spaces at the beginning or end, then he needs to simply trim it. If you mean there might be middle names, then the question will be vague because it doesn't specify weather we should put the middle name in the firstName column or in the lastName column.

Comment: parsename returns nothing if data contains more than 3 periods. Another issue is  the question is how do i split between 2nd and 3rd space(should probably have been between 1st and 2nd). You are splitting the spaces in reverse order starting from the end of the data. Consider the data "mr Thomas Hans Clausen. Should return: title=mr - firstname=Thomas - lastname=Hans Clausen. Although the data may not be that complex

Comment: Yes. But nameparse() still works for cases with even 3 spaces such as 'Mr Thomas Hans Clausen'. The other point about having a middle name added to the lastname can be handled by a combination of case and coalesce(), i.e. if the last part is NULL then there is no middle name and if it isnt then put concatenation of the last 2 parts as lastName instead. But as you said, I don't think the question asked here is that complex.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for getting back so quickly. The above script will work in my case.

Comment: @DonMercer Great! then you may want to just check the answer so that people know this question has already an accepted answer.